# Getting errors with passing parameters with fliter_by function in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have the following class for a table in SQLalchemy

```
class STDcodes(db.Model):
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
stdcode = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
city = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=False)
state = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=False)


def __init__(self, stdcode, city, state):
    self.stdcode = stdcode
    self.city = city
    self.state = state

def __repr__(self):
    return '<City {}>'.format(self.city)
```

Now I have a text file with some city names. I want to find the cities in the above database and replace their state value with something else("Telangana")
I'm trying to use the following code for doing that.

```
from flask_hello_world_app import db, STDcodes
f = open('telanganastd.txt')
lines = f.readlines()
for line in lines:
    line=line.replace("\n","")
    print line
    stdcode = STDcodes.query.filter_by(STDcodes.city.startswith(line))
    stdcode.state= "TELANGANA"
    db.session.add(stdcode)
    db.session.commit()
```

But it doesn't work.
I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/alan/Desktop/Python books/Numbersindia/replacetelangana.py", line 10, in <module>
stdcode = STDcodes.query.filter_by(STDcodes.city.startswith(line)).first()
TypeError: filter_by() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Comment: Your exception trace shows your code includes a .first() call but your code doesn't include that. Can you include your actual code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `filter`, not `filter_by`.  `filter_by` is a shortcut to `filter` that applies the equality op to keyword args, you can't use it for other ops.

`filter` takes operations, such as `User.name == 'davidism'` or `STDcodes.city.startswith(line)`, and applies them to the query.  `filter_by` is a shortcut that takes keyword arguments instead of operations, and expands them into the equivalent equality operations.  So `filter_by(name='davidism', superuser=True)` is equivalent to `filter(User.name == 'davidism', User.superuser)`.

So `filter_by` can be convenient but has limitations: all keywords are assumed to be columns on the primary model being filtered, the only operation supported is equality, and all operations are `and`'d together, there's no way to use `or`.